# when there is a new invention, there is a new name for original object, what is this called?

Tags: idiom-requests

IS there a term or lingusitic device for a name change of a noun / object that has had to change its name because of a new development. For example the invention of the electric guitar, meant the humble guitar became known as an acoustic guitar? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing a ***[retronym](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/retronym)***:

> A word or phrase created because an existing term that was once used
>   alone needs to be distinguished from a term referring to a new
>   development, as *acoustic guitar* in contrast to *electric guitar* or
>   *analog watch* in contrast to *digital watch*.

[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/retronym)